# What is the subject of the verb 'was' before 'when' in the second clause?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, subjects, verb-agreement

It was at this time of year that people believed the boundary between the worlds of living and dead became blurred, and was when the souls of the dead were said to revisit their homes.

(2) Is the expression 'the large number of' correct? in addition to 'a large number of'?
As America welcomed the large number of immigrants in the second half of the nineteenth century, with them came their Halloween traditions.

https://www.cambridgeschool.com/ca/the-origins-of-halloween-cat.html

Comment: This was partially copy-pasted from other websites and mistakes made on the way. You will find part of the original text on [History.com](https://www.history.com/topics/halloween/history-of-halloween). As you can see it is missing before was.  If you have two questions, then open another question on ELL. But you're right, that's another mistake it should be "a large number*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.